# OS X MCP_ELPG_VCORE_STS_SATA_POWERED_UP never reached! error

Tags: macos, mac, kernel

I'm using a macbook air and it keeps shutting itself down in the middle of usage and brings the following error

```
 Anonymous UUID:       3B35044A-64F2-3EA5-3C7B-5C908E62F2F6

 Mon Mar 17 23:52:31 2014
 panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f98859e28): "MCP_ELPG_VCORE_STS_SATA_POWERED_UP never    reached!\n"@/SourceCache/AppleAHCI/AppleAHCI-300.0.4/AppleMCP89AHCI.cpp:971
 Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
 0xffffff808e8b3d20 : 0xffffff8016622fa9 
 0xffffff808e8b3da0 : 0xffffff7f98859e28 
 0xffffff808e8b3dd0 : 0xffffff7f98859d0d 
 0xffffff808e8b3e10 : 0xffffff7f988599fd 
 0xffffff808e8b3e40 : 0xffffff7f9884f2d4 
 0xffffff808e8b3e70 : 0xffffff7f9885a2d2 
 0xffffff808e8b3e90 : 0xffffff7f98850f07 
 0xffffff808e8b3ec0 : 0xffffff8016ab0b9b 
 0xffffff808e8b3f20 : 0xffffff801664a23a 
 0xffffff808e8b3fb0 : 0xffffff80166d6ff7 
  Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort(3.0)[92202CCB-AA80-3852-BB32-BDB06022ECCA]@0xffffff7f9884d000->0xffffff7f9886dfff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily(2.6.5)[AB2D7D6A-B59B-3039-AE08-CBCC38208911]@0xffffff7f97bfd000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[EDA75271-4E9D-34E7-A2C5-14F0C8817D37]@0xffffff7f96cbb000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
Not yet set

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9FEA8EDC-B629-3ED2-A1A3-6521A1885953
Kernel slide:     0x0000000016400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8016600000
System model name: MacBookAir3,1 (Mac-942452F5819B1C1B)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1406516065
last loaded kext at 417540129: com.apple.driver.XsanFilter  404 (addr 0xffffff7f9828b000, size 20480)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    666.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   630.35
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2  
com.apple.driver.AppleMCP89RootPortPM   1.11
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 675.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
```

Comment: Update the operating system. Check there is no obstruction to air flow (machines behave weird if they overheat).

Comment: Reinstalled the OS and just opened the laptop. checked for looseness of the ssd and the fan for obstruction of air flow and there is none

Comment: does the problem persist? If so, perhaps the machine is broken... Perhaps somebody here can decipher your error, I'm no Apple user.

Comment: Yes the problem persists but not so often.